# Проблема подключения шрифтов

Tags: css3, шрифты, html5

Почему будет использовать шрифт `Arial`, а не`Bookman Old Style`?

```
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Bookman';
    src: url('http://xfont.ru/font/шрифт_BookmanOldStyleRegular_1296.htm'),     format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
  }

 p{
  font: bold 120% 'Bookman', Arial;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так,

```
p {
font-family: 'Bookman';
font-weight: bold;
}
```

А еще скорее ссылка ведет на html файл, а не на прямую скачку [Bookman Old Style Regular](http://xfont.ru/font/%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82_BookmanOldStyleRegular_1296.htm).
Загрузите себе шрифт или найдите прямую загрузку.

Answer (score 0):

[Ссылка для скачивания](http://xfont.ru/fonts/1/2/9/1296.ttf).